# Install a different version of Maven from the one provided by Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, apt, maven

I would like to install a package on Ubuntu 10.04.4 but would like to not use the one available in the one repository that I get when I do:

> apt-cache policy ${package}

I would actually like to use an older version.  So in my search, I would like to exclude the repo that is returned when I run the above command, i.e. search all the other repos.

Also, the above command returns only one option.  I was wondering if it always returns just the first (latest) it finds or would it have returned more options from different repos.

```
>apt-cache policy maven3
maven3:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.2.1-0~ppa1
  Version table:
     3.2.1-0~ppa1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/natecarlson/maven3/ubuntu/ lucid/main Packages
```

I want to install version 3.0.4

Comment: You can do `apt-get install pkgname=version`, but it might be helpful if you were to provide more context on what you are trying to do.

Comment: what more context can i provide you ??  i want version N-1 and the default version is N...

Comment: I did `apt-cache search maven3=3.0.4`, that did not return anything

Comment: @amphibient: Do you know what ppa contains your wanted package?

Comment: Include the complete output of `apt-cache policy` of the package you are trying to install. Remember that it should be available in the repositories to work/

Comment: What @Braiam said. I'm unclear about your situation. You get one version of maven when you run `apt-cache policy` and want to run another? Then you need to add a suitable source.

Comment: ok, i made the addition

Comment: `apt-cache policy pkgname` returns all the versions of that pkgname it finds in the sources in `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`. If you want to install 3.0.4 you need a source that has 3.0.4.

Comment: how do i find that in the vastness of the interwebs ?

Comment: @amphibient Note that if you want a particular user to be notified of your message, you need to add that users name to your message, prefaced by @. Anyway, http://ppa.launchpad.net/natecarlson/maven3/ubuntu/pool/main/m/maven3/ lists 3.0.3 as well, including the sources. This version is not listed for your Ubuntu release, but you can easily rebuild it for your release. (I see it is the version on maverick.) Would you like to know how?

Comment: yes, I would like to know how

Comment: @amphibient Done. If you need further help, please hop into main unix.sx chatroom and ping me.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14544/discussion-between-amphibient-and-faheem-mitha)

Answer (score 1):

Add the source line

```
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/natecarlson/maven3/ubuntu maverick main
```

and then run

```
apt-get source maven3
```

This will give you the unpacked source directory. Then cd into the source directory try running

```
debuild -uc -us
```

You may need to install some build dependencies before proceeding. The listed build dependencies for 3.0.3 are

```
Build-Depends: cdbs, debhelper (>= 7.0.50~), quilt
```

Comment: when i ran `apt-get source maven3`, i got `E: Malformed line 58 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list (dist parse)`

Comment: example of other entries:

 `51 deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security main restricted
 52 deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security main restricted`

Comment: @amphibient the source line might be wrong. i guessed it. What does your current line for maven3 look like? And can we do this in chat? Try using the same source line, replace `lucid` with `maverick` and replace `deb` with `deb-src`.

Comment: i uncommented the line in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/natecarlson-maven3-lucid.list`, which says `deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/natecarlson/maven3/ubuntu lucid main`